# Evaluate $\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-\large i\sigma x}}{(-x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

thank you very much for helping me with the following integral.

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-\large i\sigma x}}{(-x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n}dx$$
I have tried to find out if maybe the integral can be expressed in terms of the modified Bessel functions of the second kind, however I haven't been able to. 
I also tried to do the integral using differentiation under the integral sign, but still I can't find a solution.

Comment: This integral begs for a substitution of the form $x=\cosh t$. We then have $$(-1)^n\int_0^\infty\exp\Big(-nt-i\sigma~\cosh t\Big)\sinh t~dt,$$ which I believe can be expressed in terms of [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Comment: @Lucian Thank you very much, I looked for integral representations of the Bessel functions and the most similar expression I found is this one:$$K_{n}\left ( ic \right ){=}\int_{0}^{\infty }{e^{-ic\cosh t}\cosh (nt)} dt$$
However, I still have not been able to express the integral you posted in terms of the Bessel functions

Comment: If it's not expressible in terms of Bessel functions $($and their derivatives$)$, then it does not possess a closed form, and the best that one can hope for is an infinite series expansion, similar to those of the afore-mentioned special functions.

Comment: We have $I_\alpha(x) ~=~ \displaystyle\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi e^{\large x\cos(\theta)}\cos(\alpha\theta)~d\theta ~-~ \frac{\sin(\alpha\pi)}{\pi}\color{blue}{\int_0^\infty e^{\large-x\cosh t-\alpha t}~dt}$. Now, if it were at all possible from this and other relations to express $F_u(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{\large-x\cosh(ut)-\alpha t}~dt$ in terms of the various Bessel functions, we'd have $~-\bigg[\dfrac{d}{du}\dfrac{d}{dx}F_u(x)\bigg]_{u=1}=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{\large-x\cosh t-\alpha t}\cdot\color{red}t\cdot\sinh t~dt.~$ But how to get rid of the extra *t* ?

Comment: You are right, how to get rid of the extra $$t$$?